Termux Running easyrsa as `sudo -u root` gives me No such file or directory
I'm trying to run a sh script (easyrsa) while being in sudo -u root environment.
sudo -u root sh /data/data/com.termux/files/home/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/easyrsa

This gives me an error telling me that OpenSSL is not present (I assume because I'm running it in a different environment)
And when I try
sudo -u root /data/data/com.termux/files/home/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/easyrsa

It gives me "No such file or directory".
I tried every possible combination of commands but just can't seem to get it right.
The main issue is I'm trying to run easyrsa from a web dashboard for generating certificates, and this dashboard is running as sudo -u root and for some strange reason, it just can't find the files in termux home.
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/easyrsa
is my location of the easyrsa shell file

Which OpenSSL packages have you installed in your Termux environment?

@Robert OpenSSL 3.3.2 3 Sep 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.3.2 3 Sep 2024)
The issue is the different environment, No matter what i do i just cant generate while being in sudo -u root, After several tries trying to run it in the sudo -u root env
Easy-RSA error:
Writing 'copy_exts' to SSL config temp-file failed
This only happens if ran in sudo -u root, being a normal user or just with sudo works just fine but i need to run it within this environment due to my web dashboard

I solved the problem by setting the env PATH manually in the command and also setting the pki directory manually in the command because even if i set it in the vars file it's not recognizing the vars file itself,
env PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin sh /data/data/com.termux/files/home/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/easyrsa --pki=/data/data/com.termux/files/home/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/pki

